# syntax error, unexpected '{' in

Tags: php, mysqli

I trying to make a registration form. At this moment I'm trying to insert the input data into database. I got  syntax error, unexpected '{' in..i cant find where the error is.. Please kindly help to look at my code. Btw this the code i edited from question i post before about blank page error.. Sorry for my broken english. :D

partner_registration.php:

```
<?PHP
error_reporting(0);
include ('connect.php');


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

// The form is submitted

$c_name = ($_POST['txtName']);
$c_type = ($_POST['selType']);
$c_no = ($_POST['txtNo']);
$c_address = ($_POST['txtAddress']);
$c_city = ($_POST['txtCity']);
$c_postcode = ($_POST['txtPostcode']);
$c_state = ($_POST['selState']);
$c_country = ($_POST['selCountry']);
$c_email = ($_POST['txtEmail']);
$c_phone = ($_POST['txtPhone']);
$c_fax = ($_POST['txtFax']);


$c_name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($c_name);
$c_type = $mysqli->real_escape_string($c_type);
$c_no = $mysqli->real_escape_string($c_no);
$c_address = $mysqli->real_escape_string($c_address);
$c_city = $mysqli->real_escape_string($c_city);
$c_postcode = $mysqli->real_escape_string($c_postcode);
$c_state = $mysqli->real_escape_string($c_state);
$c_country = $mysqli->real_escape_string($c_country);
$c_email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($c_email);
$c_phone = $mysqli->real_escape_string($c_phone);
$c_fax = $mysqli->real_escape_string($c_fax);



// attempt insert query execution
if ( $insert = $mysqli->query ( "INSERT INTO tblpartner (companyName,   companyRegistration, companyNo, companyAddress, companyCity, companyPostCode, companyState, companyCountry, companyEmail, companyPhone, companyFax) VALUES ('$c_name', '$c_type', '$c_no', '$c_address', '$c_city','$c_postcode', '$c_state', '$c_country', '$c_email', '$c_phone', '$c_fax')")
{
echo("Success", $mysqli->affected_rows);
}

}

?>
```

connect.php:

```
<?php
$hostname="localhost"; //local server name default localhost
$username="root";  //mysql username default is root.
$password="1234";       //blank if no password is set for mysql.
$database="intrasystem";  //database name which you created

//Open a new connection to the MySQL server
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','1234','intrasystem');

//Output any connection error
if($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
     die('Cannot connect to database');
 }

?>
```

Comment: Can you see the error logs?

Comment: `$con` is an object. Use OOP in all instances. This `$c_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['txtName']);` is procedural.

Comment: Read `bind_param` manual and check it's first argument. Which is a string like `'sssi'` or similar.

Comment: no..nothing displays even i put the error reporting

Comment: That's why indentation was invented.. to avoid such `problems`

Comment: `error_reporting()` doesn't help. It is a runtime directive. It has effect during the runtime but your code doesn't run because it doesn't compile. PHP doesn't even attempt to run it. More, it tells where where is the error (in line 40).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
if ( $insert = $mysqli->query ( "... your sql query ...")
```

You have two opening brackets, but only one closing. Just add another closing bracket at the end:

```
if ( $insert = $mysqli->query ( "... your sql query ...") )
```

Comment: does it look like this  ( ....... '$c_email', '$c_phone', '$c_fax')")) coz i got new systax unexpected ','

Comment: I don't see any misplaced `,` in the code you posted. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them

Comment: the unexpected ',' is in the line echo("Success", $mysqli->affected_rows);  what is the proper way to write this? i tried echo("success") only but i got blank page after submit

Comment: [According to the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) the notation `echo ( string $arg1 [, string $... ] )` is perfectly valid. You can concatenate using `.` instead: `echo("Success: " . $mysqli->affected_rows);`

Comment: never mind..my fault..i left " at the button HTML..thnx for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $insert = $mysqli->query( "INSERT INTO tblpartner (companyName,   companyRegistration, companyNo, companyAddress, companyCity, companyPostCode, companyState, companyCountry, companyEmail, companyPhone, companyFax) VALUES ('".$c_name."', '".$c_type."', '".$c_no."', '".$c_address."', '".$c_city."','".$c_postcode."', '".$c_state."', '".$c_country."', '".$c_email."', '".$c_phone."', '".$c_fax."')"))
{
    echo("Success", $mysqli->affected_rows);
}
```

Use PDO next time.